# How reuse class parameter in case classes?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, case-class

I have one entity class like that:

```
case class Entity(id: Integer, name: String)
```

And class command code:

```
trait GeneralCommand {
      val id: Option[Integer]
}

sealed abstract class EntityCommands(id: Option[Integer]) extends DomainCommand {
  def this(id: Integer) = this(Option(id))
}

case class UpdateEntity(entity: Entity, id: Integer = entity.id) extends EntityCommands(id)
```

In Intellij Idea this code is not highlighted. But `sbt clean compile` complains that:

```
not found: value entity
case class UpdateEntity(entity: Entity, id: Integer = entity.id) extends EntityCommands(id)
                                                      ^
```

Is it possible to reuse parameter in case class in scala?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do that (there was a related problem somewhere on SO which I cannot find at the moment), easy solution would be to add an apply method:

```
case class UpdateEntity(entity: Entity, id: Integer) extends EntityCommands(id)

object UpdateEntity {
  def apply(ent: Entity) = new UpdateEntity(ent, ent.id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the use of the id filed in the case class? Will this suffice?

```
case class UpdateEntity(entity: Entity) extends EntityCommands(entity.id) {
  val id = Option(entity.id)
}
```

Comment: Do not compile with sbt 0.13.5 and scala 2.11 `[error]  method id needs to be a stable, immutable value
[error]   def id = Option(entity.id)
[error]       ^`

Comment: Do you have 
`extends EntityCommands(id)`?

It needs to be extends `EntityCommands(entity.id)`

Comment: Sorry about the previous comment. Ignore it. You need to use

`val id = Option(entity.id)`

You can override defs with vals but cannot override vals with defs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using multiple parameter lists:

```
case class UpdateEntity(entity: Entity)(id: Integer = entity.id) extends EntityCommands(id)
```

But this comes at the cost of impossibility to use the second parameter in pattern matching.